# Expand data frame from row vectors

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I am trying to add boolean columns to my data frame, then do a summary based on those values. Seems very simple.

The logic is based on search strings within the existing columns. So I thought I'd first create vectors using grep, identifying my "good" rows...

```
v1<-grep("bingo",df$col1)
v2<-grep("bingo",df$col2)

> head(v1)
[1]   64  741 1657 1905 2010 4116
> head(v2)
[1]  28  68 181 191 296 667
```

Then I thought I could use some kind of merge/bind/transform function to append columns to the original data frame.

```
df$add1<-cbind(df,v1)
df$add2<-cbind(df,v2)
```

But that didn't work due to "arguments imply differing number of rows"

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find `grepl` (logical grep) easier to use:

```
df$v1 <- grepl("bingo",df$col1)
df$v2 <- grepl("bingo",df$col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `v1` is rows that should be `TRUE`, you could:

```
df$bingo <- FALSE
df$bingo[v1] <- TRUE
```